# Xcode7: disable bitcode for specific cocoapods projects/binary frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

Some of binary pods and binary framework my project depends on has not been supporting `bitcode` yet, to link with them, I have to disable `bitcode` in my main project.

Is there any better idea?

Comment: As of my knowledge if you need bitcode enabled for your application, every dependencies should support bitcode